# warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am writing and reading registers from a memory map, like this:

```
//READ
return *((volatile uint32_t *) ( map + offset ));

//WRITE
*((volatile uint32_t *) ( map + offset )) = value;
```

However the compiler gives me warnings like this:

```
warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
```

How can I change my code to remove the warnings?  I am using C++ and Linux.

Comment: cast to `char*` - assuming you want *byte* offset. do you?

Comment: Yes that is right map is void*, thanks.

Comment: You need to cast `map` to a pointer to a type of size 1. The only type guaranteed by the standard to be of size 1 is `char`, hence you need to cast it to `char*`.

Comment: @barakmanos: `char` and variants (`signed char`, `unsigned char`), so that's a whooping 3 types of size `1`!

Answer (score 29):

Since `void*` is a pointer to an unknown type you can't do pointer arithmetic on it, as the compiler wouldn't know how big the thing pointed to is.

Your best bet is to cast `map` to a type that is a byte wide and then do the arithmetic. You can use [`uint8_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) for this:

```
//READ
return *((volatile uint32_t *) ( ((uint8_t*)map) + offset ));

//WRITE
*((volatile uint32_t *) ( ((uint8_t*)map)+ offset )) = value;
```

Comment: but void * is a well known type, it's an address type, it can point to any address type... I guess the solution is to static cast it to uintptr_t *, then

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to cast to `char`, as `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1.

Comment: @Artyer `uint8_t` is much more preferred and guaranteed to have a size of 1 byte.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Only `uint_least8_t` is guaranteed  to have a size of 1 byte, as `uint8_t` is not guaranteed to exist (I know this will never happen in practice, but still). Also, `uint8_t` means "8 bit number", and `char` means "byte", and `offset` is a byte offset.

Comment: @Artyer uh, I have never known about `uint_least8_t`, thank you. But I have always been thinking of `char` as a "character" and of `uint8_t` as a "byte", was I wrong all the time? :) Also, coming back to C++ from Rust that sounds really weird, that `uint8_t` is not guaranteed to exist :)

Answer (score 8):

Type void is incomplete type. Its size is unknown. So the pointer arithmetic with pointers to void has no sense. You have to cast the pointer to type void to a pointer of some other type for example to pointer to char. 
Also take into account that you may not assign an object declared with qualifier volatile.

Answer (score 4):

If the use of arithmetic on void pointers is really what you want as it is made possible by GCC (see [Arithmetic on void- and Function-Pointers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith)) you can use `-Wno-pointer-arith` to suppress the warning.